# CGRect rect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect]; depraceted

Tags: objective-c, xcode, deprecated

I have this code here:

```
CGRect rect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];
```

This gives me a deprecated warning. In order to keep things clean, I wanna make it with actual code, but I don't know how. Could anyone tell me how?

Here is the whole bunch of code:

```
- (void)fillMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect context:(CGContextRef)context {
  CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGRect rect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];
  CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
  CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
  CGContextAddPath(context, path);
  UIColor *overlayColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2];
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, overlayColor.CGColor);
  CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
  CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

**mapRectForRect:**

Returns the map rectangle that corresponds to the rectangle in the overlay view’s coordinate system. (Deprecated in iOS 7.0. Use an [MKOverlayRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayRenderer) object instead.)

Because the bounds and frame rectangles of an overlay view do not change after the view has been created, you may call this method from multiple threads simultaneously. Therefore, you may call this method safely from your view’s `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` method.